# PowerMockito returns null when mocking private method for testing public method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, mockito, junit5, powermock

I'm trying to write a Test that will compare strings' equality.

Here is a code snippet of the class that should be tested

```
package ge.jibo.util;

public class TextManager {

  private String concatenateTwoString(String t1, String t2) {
    return t1 + t2;
  }

  public String concatenate(String t1, String t2) {
    return concatenateTwoString(t1, t2);
  }

}
```

and here is a test class

```
package ge.jibo.util;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class TextManagerTest {

  @Test
  @PrepareForTest(TextManager.class)
  void checkIfConcatenationWorks() throws Exception {
    TextManager textmanager = PowerMockito.spy(new TextManager());
    PowerMockito.doReturn("someText").when(textmanager,"concatenateTwoString", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
    String text = textmanager.concatenate("ji","bo");
    assertThat(text).isEqualTo("jibo");
  }
}
```

as you see, I want to test the public method `concatenate`,  which calls the private method `concatenateTwoString` in the same class.
The idea is that I want to make a mock object for the private method, and whenever it will be called from the public method it should return the constant value `"someText"`

but it returns the `null` instead of `"someText"` from the private method `concatenateTwoString`.

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <null>
to be equal to:
 <"jibo">
but was not.
Expected :jibo
Actual   :null
```

**Does anyone know how to fix it?**

Dependency Versions:

1. junit-jupiter - 5.7.2
2. junit-platform-launcher - 1.8.1
3. mockito-core - 3.12.4
4. mockito-junit-jupiter - 3.12.4
5. powermock-core - 2.0.9
6. powermock-api-mockito2 - 2.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@heaprc` mentioned in his post, the "Test" method can be executed correctly, in the case when we use `JUnit4` instead of `JUnit5` and by adding `JUnit4` annotation for powerMock `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)`.

Everything is correct, there is no direct solution to mock the private method under the public one in the case of **JUnit5**.

**So what options do we have?**

In m.o there is three option in this case:

1. leave `JUnit5` for the `"Test framework"` and do not try to make a mock of the private method. At first, think about if you really want to test that `private` method and if it's necessary to test make it `package-private` (by changing the method to `package-private` you are breaking the concept of encapsulation, but if you relly need to test it, then I think it's not a big problem)
2. downgrade your `"Test framework"` from `JUnit5` to `JUnit4`. but in this case, if you already wrote 100 tests in `JUnit5` you will have to change all of them to work on `JUnit4`. The fact that you have to downgrade your framework is really annoying, and the fact that you have to rewrite 100 tests for `JUnit4` is very irritant.
3. make `JUnit4` and `JUnit5` work together. I think this is the better solution and here is the example:

you have to have the following dependencies in your `pom.xml` file.

### **pom.xml**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.8.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

- `junit-vintage-engine` allows you to run `JUnit4` test.
- `junit-jupiter-engine` allows you to run `JUnit5` test.

### **Code snippet**

```
    import org.junit.Assert;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
    import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import org.mockito.Mockito;
    import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
    import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
    import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    
    @PrepareForTest(TextManager.class)
    @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
    public class TextManagerTest {
    
        @org.junit.Test  //Test using Junit4
        public void checkIfConcatenationWorksWithJunit4() throws Exception {
            TextManager textmanager = PowerMockito.spy(new TextManager());
            PowerMockito.doReturn("jibo").when(textmanager, "concatenateTwoString", Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString());
            String text = textmanager.concatenate("ji", "bo");
            Assert.assertEquals(text,"jibo");
        }
    
        @Test  //Test using Junit5
        public void checkIfConcatenationWorksWithJunit5() {
            Assertions.assertEquals("text","jibo");
        }
    }
```

in this case, you will run the `checkIfConcatenationWorksWithJunit4` test method with the `Junit4` platform, and `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` will work for this execution.
in the case of `checkIfConcatenationWorksWithJunit5` method, it will run with the Junit5(Jupiter) platform.

### **Finally**

you have to add `maven-surefire-plugin` in the `pom.xml` file to make both `JUnit4` and `JUnit5` tests to be tested while building it or testing using `maven commands`.

```
   <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

without adding `maven-surefire-plugin` the only one platform `(JUnit4)` test will be executed at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to add `@RunWith` and specify the `PowerMockRunner`

If you are able to use **Junit-4** this is the solution.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(TextManager.class)
public class TextManagerTest {

  @Test
  public void checkIfConcatenationWorks() throws Exception {
    // Arrange
    TextManager textmanager = PowerMockito.spy(new TextManager());
    PowerMockito.doReturn("someText").when(textmanager,"concatenateTwoString"
    , Mockito.anyString()
    , Mockito.anyString());

    // Act
    String text = textmanager.concatenate("ji","bo");

    // Assert
    assertThat(text).isEqualTo("jibo");
  }
}
```

Comment: I add @RunWith annotation but nothing has changed.

Comment: If I change the 'concatenateTwoString' method from private to package-private, then it works perfectly. can't understand the reason.

Comment: RunWith and Jupiter do not go together.

Comment: @heaprc your recommendation to add "@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)" annotation works in case of junit4 but do you how to fix the issue in case of Junit5?